# redux-sage sagas in multiple files

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have multiple sagas in multiple files, I need to combine then together into one rootSaga.

in saga1.js

```
function* fetchStores() {
  // API call
}

function* fetchStore(action) {
  // Another API call
}

export default function* storeSagas() {
  yield all([
    fork(actions.GET_STORES, fetchStores),
    fork(actions.GET_STORE, fetchStore)
  ]);
}
```

in saga2.js

```
function* fetchItems() {
  // API call
}

function* fetchItem(action) {
  // Another API call
}

export default function* itemSagas() {
  yield all([
    fork(actions.GET_ITEMS, fetchItems),
    fork(actions.GET_ITEM, fetchItem)
  ]);
}
```

in sagas.js

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    storeSagas(),
    itemSagas()
  ]);
}
```

and in store.js

```
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    ...reducers
  }),
  applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware, logger)
);
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
```

This is not working. I reckon the reducers and actions are working fine. I guess this is not working because of yield or fork or takeEvery etc.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason why `itemsSagas` and `storeSagas` need to be generators? Just wondering if you could return an array of effects (omit the `yield all`) from a regular function and then call `yield all([...storeSagas(), ...itemSagas()])` in your root saga.

Comment: Cheers mate, appreciate it. Works like charm

Answer (score 1):

**Fork**

`fork(actions.GET_ITEMS, fetchItems)`

First, the syntax which are using for the fork is wrong. fork takes first argument as a function and second argument for the parameters to be passed to that function.

`fork(fetchItems,actions.GET_ITEMS)`

fork is used to perform the non-blocking task and return the Task object.

**TakeEvery**

`takeEvery` allows concurrent actions to be handled. It will take pattern, saga function and arguments to be passed to the started task.

`yield takeEvery(actions.GET_STORES, fetchStores)`

In your code just replace the `fork` with the `takeEvery` and it will work as expected.